# Facebook App ask permission for user_likes works only for some users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm making test Meteor (JS) app, and after click on "login with facebook" every user should be asked to give permission to his "user_likes", but it asks only for public profile and friend list. When I switch to another facebook account - my private one and try to login using facebook, there is a full list of permissions I needed: public profile, friend and likes.

Is that a thing of some configuration on my facebook user profile to change?

user 1 login window:
[image: user 1]

userr 2 login window:
[image: user 2]

Answer (score 4):

I assume you don´t know about [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review) yet. Most permissions need to get approved by Facebook before they can be used in a public App. Without review, those permissions will only work for App Admins/Developers/Testers.

Comment: I have just asked this question a friend of mine who is fb app developer and suggested the same thing, so I hope it will work out after Review...